# What encoding to set for mysql?

Tags: mysql, ruby, encoding

Now i have utf8_unicode_ci, but when i import my data:

```
Код № по каталогу  (артикул)    Наименование  товара    Ед. изм.    Цена опт.   Доп.    Остатки | Минск Класс   Группа  Бренд
96528   AH-36АЕТ    ASIAN HORSE 36з евр (тонк.кл.) 280A (187x127x227)                                                       шт      38,58           Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      ASIAN HORSE до 100А                                                                                     ASIAN HORSE
96529   AH-36АRТ    ASIAN HORSE 36з рус (тонк.кл.) 280A (187x127x227)                                                       шт      38,58           Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      ASIAN HORSE до 100А                                                                                     ASIAN HORSE
88634   AH-45АЕТ    ASIAN HORSE 45з евр 300A (238x129x227) (545158033)                                                      шт      46,14           Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      ASIAN HORSE до 100А                                                                                     ASIAN HORSE
82978   AH-45АЕ ASIAN HORSE 45з евр 300A тонк.клемы  (238x129x227) (545157033)                                          шт      36,57       >8  Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      ASIAN HORSE до 100А                                                                                     ASIAN HORSE
96531   AH-60АЕ ASIAN HORSE 60з евр 510A (232x173x225)                                                                  шт      48,76           Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      ASIAN HORSE до 100А                                                                                     ASIAN HORSE
82979   AH-70АЕ ASIAN HORSE 70з евр 600A (261x175x220)                                                                  шт      56,92       3   Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      ASIAN HORSE до 100А                                                                                     ASIAN HORSE
96530   AH-70АR ASIAN HORSE 70з рус 600A (261x175x220)                                                                  шт      56,92       >8  Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      ASIAN HORSE до 100А                                                                                     ASIAN HORSE
82980   AH-95АЕ ASIAN HORSE 95з евр 760A (306x173x225)                                                                  шт      77,21       >8  Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      ASIAN HORSE до 100А                                                                                     ASIAN HORSE
96532   AH-95АR ASIAN HORSE 95з рус 760A (306x173x225)                                                                  шт      77,21       >8  Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      ASIAN HORSE до 100А                                                                                     ASIAN HORSE
25335   600 103 085 Бэрен polar 100з (600103) 850A (353x175x190)                                                            шт      107,42          Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      BAREN до 100 A                                                                                          BAREN
102137  600 150 087 / L5 100    Бэрен polar 100з (600150) 870A (353x175x190)                                                            шт      94,7            Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      BAREN до 100 A                                                                                          BAREN
25332   544 111 042 / L1B 44    Бэрен polar 44з (544111) 420A (207x175x175)                                                             шт      47,83       4   Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      BAREN до 100 A                                                                                          BAREN
```

in db i see

```
1   ASIAN HORSE AH-36???    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    ASIAN HORSE 36? ??? (????.??.) 280A (187x127x227) ...
      Изменить    Быстрая правка      Копировать     Удалить    2   ASIAN HORSE AH-36?R?    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    ASIAN HORSE 36? ??? (????.??.) 280A (187x127x227) ...
      Изменить    Быстрая правка      Копировать     Удалить    3   ASIAN HORSE AH-45???    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    ASIAN HORSE 45? ??? 300A (238x129x227) (545158033)...
      Изменить    Быстрая правка      Копировать     Удалить    4   ASIAN HORSE AH-45?? NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    ASIAN HORSE 45? ??? 300A ????.?????  (238x129x227)...
      Изменить    Быстрая правка      Копировать     Удалить    5   ASIAN HORSE AH-60?? NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    ASIAN HORSE 60? ??? 510A (232x173x225)            ...
      Изменить    Быстрая правка      Копировать     Удалить    6   ASIAN HORSE AH-70?? NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    ASIAN HORSE 70? ??? 600A (261x175x220)            ...
      Изменить    Быстрая правка      Копировать     Удалить    7   ASIAN HORSE AH-70?R NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    ASIAN HORSE 70? ??? 600A (261x175x220)            ...
      Изменить    Быстрая правка      Копировать     Удалить    8   ASIAN HORSE AH-95?? NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    ASIAN HORSE 95? ??? 760A (306x173x225)            ...
      Изменить    Быстрая правка      Копировать     Удалить    9   ASIAN HORSE AH-95?R NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    ASIAN HORSE 95? ??? 760A (306x173x225)            ...
      Изменить    Быстрая правка      Копировать     Удалить    10  BAREN   600 103 085 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    ????? polar 100? (600103) 850A (353x175x190)      ...
```

to lot ???? )) (from phpmyadmin, so i get also Изменить   Быстрая правка      Копировать     Удалить)
How encode this `????? polar 100?`

Comment: What's the encoding of the data you're trying to import? ISO-8859-x?

Comment: in rails i have such thing while importing csv: ISO-8859-15:UTF-8 ...

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson if i see here http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=ru  default - win1251 view as iso8859-15 i see what i need... but how do this in mysql and rails?

Comment: Export, some `iconv` magic on the text file, import.